# How do you get a TFS Build Agent to Compile SASS to CSS

Tags: css, tfs, build, msbuild, sass

We have developers on VS2013.4 using Web Essentials Extension on their local machines to build the app. Our Continuous Integration Build Server Compiles and deploys the app. However I cannot find anyway way to configure MSBuild to compile SASS. The build server has VS installed along with Web Essentials also.